# urllib.request.Request() always ends in HTTP Error 400 issue

Tags: python

When using the Request object from urllib to fetch an URL I always end up with HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.

I wanted to create a watch2gether room where u can post for example an YouTube URL and it automatically creates a watch2gether room so u can share the Video.
If I try to do it like this :

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
import urllib.response

wurl = "https://w2g.tv/rooms/create.json"

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

items = []
 
body_create = {"w2g_api_key": "TOKEN", "share": " ","bg_color": "#00ff00", "bg_opacity": "50" }

body_update = { "w2g_api_key": "TOKEN","item_url" : " " }

class watch2gether():
    def createroom(self, url : str): 
        body_create['share'] = url
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(body_create).encode("utf-8")
        req = urllib.request.Request(wurl, data, headers)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response: 
            source = response.read()
            dict = json.loads(source)
            items.append(dict['streamkey'])
        return items[0]   

    def updateroom(self, url: str): 
            input_url = f"https://w2g.tv/rooms/{items[0]}/sync_update"
            body_update['item_url'] = url
            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(body_update).encode("utf-8")
            urllib.request.urlopen(input_url, data)

s1 = watch2gether()

user_url = str(input("post url to create room: "))
print("hey here is your link https://w2g.tv/rooms/" + s1.createroom(user_url))

new_url = str(input("post link to update room: " ))
s1.updateroom(new_url)
```

I get this response:

```
post url to create room: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RJKBNN4dTw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/w2g.py", line 47, in <module>
    print("hey here is your link https://w2g.tv/rooms/" + s1.createroom(user_url))
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/Desktop/Discordbot/w2g.py", line 27, in createroom
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req, data) as response: 
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/jannitselekoglou/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

However, if I just use the **urlopen()** method without passing in headers it works perfectly.
( You can read the Watch2Gether API Documentation [here](https://community.w2g.tv/t/watch2gether-api-documentation/133767), its very short)

I don't really understand what it is I am doing wrong with *urllib.request.Request()* and why I don't need to pass in headers as the API Documentation specifically states that u have to do so **" Make sure to set the content type of your request to application/json"**.

Comment: 400 is the http code for bad request meaning you did not provide the right parameters to the request, Have you tried your request with postman or curl to see what the response code was ?

Comment: First time hearing about postman, but when using it to send a request from "https://w2g.tv/rooms/create.json", as response I get the streamkey which Is necessary to create the new room. 
What exactly do I need to look for? For example, do I have to consider cookies or something (bare in mind im a beginner )?

Comment: first try to request the url you are requesting in python with curl for example `curl -XPOST --data '{your data here}' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RJKBNN4dTw`, if it returns a 400 then you request is lacking a parameter or a cookie.

Comment: Thats the response I got, so no 400 here 

{"id":219202442,"streamkey":"uix28kgke19zd8ldez","created_at":"2021-09-18T13:30:05.000Z","persistent":false,"persistent_name":null,"deleted":false,"moderated":false,"location":"EU","stream_created":false,"background":null,"moderated_background":false,"moderated_playlist":false,"bg_color":"FFFFFF","bg_opacity":100.0,"moderated_item":false,"theme_bg":null,"playlist_id":211133171,"members_only":false,"moderated_suggestions":false,"moderated_chat":false,"moderated_user":false,"moderated_cam":false}%

Comment: What exactly is the difference between using only urlopen and using the Request object with urlopen? Because as I said with urlopen it works somehow.

Comment: I don't know this lib enough to answer you but i guess you might find your answers at the documentation page of `urlib` or at google.